# Prove recursion: Show that M(n) >= 1/2 (n + 1) lg(n + 1)

Tags: recursion, proof

I want to show that the recursion of quicksort run on best time time on n log n.

i got this recursion formula

```
M(0) = 1
M(1) = 1
M(n) = min (0 <= k <= n-1) {M(K) + M(n - k - 1)} + n

show that M(n) >= 1/2 (n + 1) lg(n + 1)
```

what i have got so far:

```
By induction hyposes

M(n) <= min {M(k) + M(n - k - 1} + n
```

focusing on the inner expresison i got:

```
1/2(k + 1)lg(k + 1) + 1/2(n - k)lg(n - k)
1/2lg(k + 1)^(k + 1) + 1/2lg(n - k)^(n - k)
1/2(lg(k + 1)^(k + 1) + lg(n - k)^(n - k)
1/2(lg((k + 1)^(k + 1) . (n - k)^(n - k))
```

But i think im doing something wrong. i think the "k" should be gonne but i cant see how this equation would cancel out all the "k". So, probably, im doing something wrong

Comment: Are you using any software to help you produce a proof? I suppose this belongs to https://mathoverflow.net and not here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed want to get rid of `k`. To do this, you want to find the lower bound on the minimum of `M(k) + M(n - k - 1)`. In general it can be arbitrarily tricky, but in this case the standard approach works: take derivative by `k`.

```
((k+1) ln(k+1) + (n-k) ln(n-k))' =
ln(k+1) + (k+1)/(k+1) - ln(n-k) - (n-k)/(n-k) =
ln((k+1) / (n-k))
```

We want the derivative to be `0`, so

```
ln((k+1) / (n-k)) = 0 <=>
(k+1) / (n-k) = 1 <=>
k + 1 = n - k <=>
k = (n-1) / 2
```

You can check that it's indeed a local minimum.
Therefore, the best lower bound on `M(k) + M(n - k - 1)` (which we can get from the inductive hypothesis) is reached for `k=(n-1)/2`. Now you can just substitute this value instead of `k`, and `n` will be your only remaining variable.